# How can I work with two sites simultaneously from the Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to automate my work. I'm working with two sites, I've written code that itself presses all the buttons. Now I need to embed this site in another via iframe, I did it like this:

```
var adte5 = document.createElement('div');
adte5.innerHTML = '<iframe id="myframe1" src="https://website2.com" width="900" height="450" align="left"></iframe>';
            adte5.style.display = "block";
            adte5.style.position = "absolute";
            adte5.style.top = "1px";
            adte5.style.left = "1px";
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(adte5);
```

Now I'm trying to click on the buttons on this page, but I get an error:

```
function rightckicksim(sima)
{

    var element = document.getElementById('myframe1').contentDocument.getElementById(sima);
var e = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');

e.initMouseEvent('contextmenu', true, true,
     element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, false,
     false, false, false,2, null);


return !element.dispatchEvent(e);
}
rightckicksim('idButton1');
```

Error:

```
Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://website2.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

What should I do? Is there any way to enable access? Or is it possible to manage two tabs at the same time? Can I transfer information from one tab to another?

But it is desirable to do this through the iframe.

Comment: You can't directly access cross-origin frames. Declare a content script and use messaging to coordinate the work.

Comment: @wOxxOm How to do it?

Comment: Do what? You can look at [examples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) and [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).